# Did Jesus and the repentant thief reunite in heaven on the very day they died?(Catholic view)

Tags: catholicism, exegesis, gospel-of-luke, resurrection-of-jesus, thief-on-the-cross

The reading of Luke 23:43 differs depending on how we punctuate it:

> And Jesus said unto him, Verily I say unto thee, Today shalt thou be with me in paradise.

Or

> And Jesus said unto him, Verily I say unto thee today, shalt thou be with me in paradise.

It seems that in fact the repentant thief was granted salvation by Jesus Christ but does not seem possible that before sundown on Nisan 14 both Jesus and the thief were together in heaven since after Jesus resurection he told Mary Magdalene "I have not yet ascended...."

Does the Catholic Church teach that Jesus and the repentant thief were resurrected to heaven on the same day they died?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Catholic Church certainly teaches that the good thief—often traditionally called St. Dismas—did in fact merit and receive salvation:

> The parable of the poor man Lazarus **and the words of Christ on the cross to the good thief**, as well as other New Testament texts speak of a final destiny of the soul—a destiny which can be different for some and for others.

(*Catechism of the Catholic Church*, paragraph 1021; emphasis added)

As for when this occurred:

> Each man receives his eternal retribution in his immortal soul **at the very moment of his death**, in a particular judgment that refers his life to Christ: either entrance into the blessedness of heaven—through a purification or immediately,—or immediate and everlasting damnation.

(*Catechism* paragraph 1022; emphasis added)

Of course, after death, it's arguable that time doesn't have much meaning; so asking whether after death someone was "in heaven" on the 14th of the month or not until later, or asking how long someone spends in Purgatory, probably doesn't make sense. That being the case, Catholic commentators seem to have argued that **it is best to believe that indeed the thief was in Heaven as soon as Jesus died**. [Richard Challoner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Challoner), who revised and edited the Catholic Douay-Rheims Bible, stated in a footnote to the passage:

> Christ was pleased, by a special privilege, to reward the faith and confession of the penitent thief, with a full discharge of all his sins, both as to the guilt and punishment; and to introduce him immediately after death into the happy society of the saints, whose limbo, that is, the place of their confinement, was now made a paradise by our Lord's going thither.

Comment: Could you add to address the thought that Jesus did not as ascended to heaven  until many days later so could not be with the thief even if the theif was immediately there? And if there is any particular reason for rejecting the alternate placement of the comma which would make this verse have no conflict

Comment: the above comment did you see it ?

Comment: I did, thanks - apologies, I've been really busy with work. I'll do my best to update the answer in the next day or so.

Comment: you okay brother?

Comment: @Kris Been busy and sick. Bad combination.

Comment: The thief was still alive  at the moment Jesus died.

Comment: Hi Matt you still check in here?

Comment: Every so often (though I'm just about to go to bed at the moment).

Comment: @Kris and Matt Gutting.  I too, look forward to more details on your answer.  I hope you're now fully healed after 4 years ;-)